# Why can scala not Infer that Left[X,A] is a reasonable subtype of Either[X,B]?

Tags: scala, type-systems

Why does this code not type check?

```
def foo: Either[String, List[Int]] = {  
  val x = null: Either[String, String]

  x match {
    case l @ Left(_) => l
    case Right(_) => Right(List(3))
  }
}
```

Specifically, why can't/doesn't the compiler reify the type of Left[A,X] and Either[A,B]?

This happened in scala 2.8.2 and scala 2.9.2

Comment: Why not use `case Left(v) => Left(v)`, or `x.right.map(r => List(3))`?

Comment: Interesting! Replacing ``case l @ Left(a) => l`` by ``case l @ Left(a) => Left(a)`` makes Scala 2.9.2 happy. What Scala version(s) did you try?

Comment: Yes, that's because `Left(a)` has type `Left[String, Nothing]`, which is a subtype of `Either[String, List[Int]]`. Or as I wrote above, use `right.map` to avoid the whole match expression.

Comment: @robinst Because my useage of either isn't a simple if left this, if right that

Comment: @robinst But in ``case l @ Left(a) => l`` ``l`` is bound to ``Left(a)``, so it seems as if the compiler loses some information here. At least I don't see a real difference to ``case l @ Left(a) => Left(a)``.

Comment: @mhs - In the latter case, you are _re-creating_ the `Left` as `Left[A, Nothing](a)`.  But `l` is typed as `l @ Left[String, String](a)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a genuine conflict here:

```
Left[String, String] <: Either[String, List[Int]]
```

is not true.  `Left` is typed on *both left and right parameters*, and even though there is no *actual* difference between the two (so casting would be safe), this is *not what you have told the compiler*.  So, of course, it will complain.

There are other weaknesses in type inference in pattern matching, but this is not one of them.

---

Edit: one can imagine an alternate singly-parameterized implementation of `Left` in which

```
Left[String] <: Either[String, Nothing] <: Either[String, List[Int]]
```

which would throw away type information.  Methods like `swap` would be tricker to use, but it would allow the pattern given by the OP.  However, the type-preserving form was used in the standard implementation in Scala.

Comment: Why is either typed on both parameters then? Would it not be a better idea to have Left[A] <: Either[A, Any] ?

Comment: @MrBones - You could have a singly-typed `Left`, but then when working with `Left`s you would forget what the corresponding `Right` was.  There are arguments for doing it each way; if your `Left`s know what the `Right`s should hold, then you can map to `Right` more easily in a type-safe way.  But, as you've seen here, if the `Left` knows what the `Right` should be, the type system will complain when you try to use a `Left` with a differently-typed right data type.  Neither is the "right" way; there are just different tradeoffs.

Comment: The reason is that in an ideal world, Left and Right would not be types, but constructors. The fact that inheritance is being used to encode an algebraic data type is the problem. In short, the left and right constructors (and extractors) are relevant for constructing and inspecting instances, but should not be considered types; the only type is Either. What you're doing in your example is actually typecasing, which is usually a design smell. My advice would be to use either.fold instead; this will enforce good practice.

Comment: @KrisNuttycombe - I don't find that world ideal.  Sometimes I like my types to tell me whether I have a `Left` or a `Right`; sometimes it's a nuisance.

Comment: If your types can tell you it's a Left[A] or a Right[B], then whatever's using that knowledge can just use the unwrapped A or B directly. This will make for better compositionality.

Comment: @KrisNuttycombe - Often, yes.  Sometimes _that it is a `Left`_ is the clearest indication of what that code path is for--if I'm sorting input into parseable and unparseable branches, for instance, I might use `Either[String,String]` for a while, with the leftness of some strings telling me that there's something problematic about them.  A generic tracking system (c.f. effects tracking) would be even better, typically, but I'll take whatever we've got for the time being.