# Scala: Match Left and return Left without unwrapping the object

Tags: scala

I have a use case where I want to return a Future of a Left. Where as I get that unwrapped and create it again:

```
fooEither match {
    case Right(value) => //.. Some logic. returns Future(Right(MyObj))
    case Left(value) => Future(Left(value))
}
```

I want to get rid of the object creation again in the second case.
Something like:

```
fooEither match {
    case Right(value) => //.. Some logic. returns Future(Right(MyObj))
    case left: Left(_) => Future(left)
}
```

It gives me a compilation error for Type mismatch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aliasing objects from expensive statements in Scala pattern match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21433678/aliasing-objects-from-expensive-statements-in-scala-pattern-match)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848594/why-can-scala-not-infer-that-leftx-a-is-a-reasonable-subtype-of-eitherx-b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Left` carries both type arguments of the `Either` super-type:

```
trait Foo; trait Bar; trait Quux

import scala.concurrent.Future

def test(e: Either[Foo, Bar]): Future[Either[Foo, Quux]] = e match {
  case Right(bar) => Future.successful(Right(new Quux {}))
  case left: Left[Foo, Bar] => Future.successful(left) // XXX
}
```

This doesn't compile because in `// XXX` you try to return a `Future[Either[Foo, Bar]]`. The following works, however:

```
def test(e: Either[Foo, Bar]): Future[Either[Foo, Quux]] = e match {
  case Right(bar) => Future.successful(Right(new Quux {}))
  case left: Left[Foo, Nothing] => Future.successful(left)
}
```

Although the compiler emits a warning:

> ```
> warning: non-variable type argument Nothing in type pattern scala.util.Left[Foo,Nothing] (the underlying of Left[Foo,Nothing]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
>      case left: Left[Foo, Nothing] => Future.successful(left)
>                 ^
> ```

This is "safe", because you can never get an element of the second type parameter from a `Left`, but it's "dirty", as if you would cast your left to `Left[Foo, Quux]`. I recommend to reconstruct the `Left` which will then get the correct type by inference.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather use [pattern binders](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-binders) for this instead of reproducing the full type parameters of `Either` type, like so:

```
case left @ Left(_) => Future.successful(left)
```

Comment: This has the same problem, the `left` you are binding here has the wrong `B` type. You either have to cast it or reconstruct the `Left`.

Comment: Sorry, the question did not say anything of the A,B types of the Either/Left/Right. I assumed they were the same.